# How to connect xamarin.forms app to azure?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am at the point in azure manager where I have to choose for xamarin.forms: create new app(too much unnecessary content) or connect an existing app(which I think is better). I have a blank xamarin.forms project and I cannot figure out in which specific files to put necessary items, basically I would like to know the file names and place to put each item in according to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc9ZO.jpg)(starting from "In your main Activity file...").For example, which is the main Activity file?

Comment: MainActivity refers to your Android project

Comment: Thanks, thought main Activity file meant something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Xamarin.form app with Azure, you can take a look the following article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started

And you could be confused about xamarin.form folder, when you click corss-platform---Mobile App---OK, your solution will be created with four projects, you will have three platform-specific projects and one Shared Project. The Shared Project contains the application logic as well as all the Xamarin.Forms code that will be in charge of creating the screens (Page objects) of your application. More detailed info, you can take a look the following article---Creating basic Application.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-xamarinforms-basics--cms-21564